# How to sum all 1,000 rows to get 1,000 sums in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 1,000X1,000 columns and rows full of numbers. If I want to sum each rows, from Row 1 to the last 1,000 rows. Each row has 1,000 numbers in each columns, I want to sum this up

Comment: To clarify, you want to sum all the numbers in the first row, then all the numbers in the second row, etc. Correct?

Answer (score 2):

To sum the first 1000 cells in Row 1, add a cell with this formula:

```
=SUM($A1:$ALL1)
```

Then, copy-paste that cell into 999 cells below it. The formulas will read:

```
=SUM($A2:$ALL2)
=SUM($A3:$ALL3)
...
```

Comment: I have to copy paste every row each time? that seems a waste of time. Isn't it easier to drag the formula down? It takes like 30 seconds

Comment: Yes, dragging the formula down is a quick way to copy-paste. Another quick way is to select all the cells and Ctrl-V paste.